# Are there rules and guidelines anywhere for loot in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, treasure

My players are used to playing RPG's on PC and love getting new weapons and loot. I can't really find much in the PHB or basic DM guide.
I have been using http://redkatart.com/treasure5e/treasureGen.php up until now but it seems to only give gold and gems, and I would like to be able to make custom shops with randomized inventories to add a little flavour to my towns.
Even just a run down of equipment milestones players tend to need by certain levels or explanation of the whole "masterwork" weapon systems would be fine. Just something so I don't give them the "Sword of 1000 Truths" at level 3 and accidentally ruin the balance of everything.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees On the other hand, magic loot in 4e is merely functional rather than wonderful, so may not be interesting if they're in it for that "oooh, shiny" feel.

Comment: A couple of related questions: [Does the DM have to give me magical weapons?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46376/does-the-dm-have-to-give-me-magical-weapons) and [Without a magic item economy, what is gold for?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47604/without-a-magic-item-economy-what-is-gold-for) Those might help show why "equipment milestones" like 4e has aren't anticipated to be part of 5e's treasure system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, we won't see these guidelines (unless part of them show up in the previews), until the DMG.

So I can state confidently, that these rules do not exist in official published materials.

For now that treasure generator looks like a pretty solid option.

With respect to creating your own shops, unfortunately, the economy is based around magic items being rare enough that they are *incredibly* hard to both purchase and sell, so I'm not sure we'll see a list of shop inventories in 5e. The best I can do there is that the starter set has some guidelines on what *mundane* items shops in Phandalin have.

With respect to recommended items per level, again this is advice we simply don't have. But it's worth noting that in general items we've seen *don't have levels.* That doesn't necessarily means they wouldn't be overpowered for certain characters and underpowered for others, it just means we haven't seen levels attached to them. We have seen +1 attached to weapons and armor, so certainly you wouldn't want to give a L1 character a +2 or +3 weapon/armor, but beyond that the guidelines are non-exisistant at this time.

Comment: The DMG has been out for a while, perhaps we can update this answer to include the rules from DMG?

Comment: @eirvandelden I second this - it's been *quite* some time now, and an updated answer would certainly be beneficial.