# Can a concentration spell be cast without actually concentrating on it for an "instant" effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, concentration

The book says:

> **Concentration.** Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep
>   their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.

So what happens if, for example, you are already concentrating on a spell, and cast Witch Bolt without concentrating. Would you get the initial arc of blue energy, or would it not even go off?

I am asking if you can cast a spell that says concentration without concentrating for an immediate effect. This would be useful to avoid interrupting your existing concentration. In essence, if you are concentrating on *thing A* (doesn't have to be a spell since other things need concentration), can you cast a concentration spell getting an immediate effect without losing concentration on *thing A*?

Since the definition of concentration is to keep the spell active (meaning it is already active) I would think that you would get the initial effect (if it had one) without the need to concentrate on it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### No. Casting a concentration spell immediately breaks any existing concentration.

One of the rules clarifications in Xanathar's Guide to Everything (pg. 5) addresses this issue directly:

> As soon as you start casting a spell or using a special ability that requires concentration, your concentration on another effect ends instantly.

Comment: This question is also now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf): "**If I’m concentrating on a spell and I cast another spell that requires concentration, when does my concentration on the first spell end?** If you’re concentrating on a spell, your concentration on it ends immediately when you start casting another spell that requires concentration." You may want to update your answer accordingly

Answer (score 10):

### A concentration spell requires concentration  *all the time*

You concentrate on a concentration spell from the instant you start to cast it until you stop concentrating. As such any previous concentration spell loses concentration at that instant.

Comment: But why? This answer could be improved by citing the relevant rules.