# Mind spike while concentrating in another spell

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration

The warlock in my party is planning to learn *Shadow blade* and *Mind spike* spells (both require concentration). As far I know, you lose your concentration in a given spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration.

Let's say the Warlock cast *Shadow blade* and the following round he cast Mind spike. He is interested in the direct damage (3d8). Could he opt to no concentrate in the *Mind Spike* and keep concentrating in the Shadow Blade?

Comment: In fact just found now, that this was already answered:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113052/can-a-concentration-spell-be-cast-without-actually-concentrating-on-it-for-an-i?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot cast Mind Spike if you want to keep concentrating on something else.

The language on the topic is quite strict; quoting from "Casting a spell" in the Player's Handbook, with some emphasis by me:

> If a spell **must** be maintained with concentration,
> that fact appears in its Duration entry, and the spell
> specifies how long you can concentrate on it. You can
> end concentration at any time (no action required).

> **Casting another spell that requires concentration.**
> You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another
> spell that requires concentration.

You need Concentration to cast the spell; and doing so breaks the concentration on the other spell.

Answer (score 1):

The rule says:

> The following factors can break concentration:
>
> Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose
> concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires
> concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once.

Thus casting mind spike requires concentration and stops the previously called Shadow Blade

I guess the confusion comes from the phrase:

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.

which gives the impression, that it's not the casting, that requires concentration, but 'just' the maintaining.