# Are there any official mechanics for grafts or anything similar?

Tags: dnd-5e

In D&D 3.5e there were [a number of options](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?190350-Fleshwarping-A-List-of-Grafts-Symbionts-and-Related-Goodies) which PC's (and the DM) could use to augment themselves (or monsters) for a cost. Of these numerous options, I am focusing on grafts.

Has anything similar to grafts from D&D 3.5e been introduced in D&D 5e so far? Certain grafts were iconic to certain enemy types such as beholders, aboleths, etc., and I would like to use something similar if it is available (or even if they have been mentioned) rather than attempting to introduce them as homebrew.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, there isn't anything official (besides some artifacts)

At this point, WotC have not provided any 'grafting' rules for 5e.

But there are two [artifacts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#Artifacts) mentioned in the DMG (Chapter 7, starting on p. 219) that are the closest to "Grafting":

> An artifact is a unique magic item of tremendous power, with its own origin and history. An artifact might have been created by gods or mortals of awesome power. It could have been created in the midst of a crisis that threatened a kingdom, a world, or the entire multiverse, and carry the weight of that pivotal moment in history...
>
> Characters don’t typically find artifacts in the normal course of adventuring. In  fact, artifacts only appear when you want them to, for they are as much plot devices as magic items. Tracking down and recovering an artifact is often the main goal of an adventure. Characters must chase down rumors, undergo significant trials, and venture into dangerous, half-forgotten places to find the artifact they seek. Alternatively, a major villain might already have the artifact. Obtaining and destroying the artifact could be the only way to ensure that its power can’t be used for evil.

The two Artifacts are the [Hand and Eye of Vecna](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#EyeandHandofVecna) (p. 224):

> To attune to the eye, you must gouge out your own eye and press the artifact into the empty socket. The eye grafts itself to your head and remains there until you die. Once in place, the eye transforms into a golden eye with a slit for a pupil, much like that of a cat. If the eye is ever removed, you die.
>
> To attune to the hand, you must lop off your left hand at the wrist and the press the artifact against the stump. The hand grafts itself to your arm and becomes a functioning appendage. If the hand is ever removed, you die.

Comment: Paywall links shouldn't be here, but it turns out one of its abilities is "having a Wikipedia page":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vecna#Hand_and_Eye_of_Vecna

Comment: @Harper: The quoted text is directly taken from the DMG - there's no way to link to the source of the text that's not "paywalled". D&D Beyond links are perfectly fine to include, though ideally the book/page number is also listed (I've now edited them in) so that users can check the source no matter what form they own it in. Related meta: [Stance on using D&D Beyond for references?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/stance-on-using-dd-beyond-for-references)

Comment: Well that is slightly unfortunate given the nature of how artifacts are treated in 5e, I was hopping for something a bit easier to access but in the end I guess I can resort to homebrew until something (if ever) is released.

Answer (score 0):

### Official, not yet

There is a third-party class "[The Grafter](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/262773/The-Grafter)", although I haven't tried it myself and can't really assess it:

[image]

> Did you ever get jealous of those sweet abilities monsters have? This is no longer an issue! With the Grafter class you can slowly but surely become a monstrous abomination yourself with all the sweet perks it brings! This is a class for those who like to hunt down monsters for their parts and then use those parts in battle!
>
> The grafter class includes three archetypes: the monster, the symbiont and the witch.

### Besides...

There are a couple of related spells and magic items:

- The necromancy "[Graft](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/198672-graft)" spell allows you to attach a dead limb.
- The infamous Eye of Vecna and Hand of Vecna from the DMG attaches instead of your own eye or hand

Comment: Have you tried this class out and can discuss it's balance and quality?

Comment: If you are going to mention the eye and hand of vecna, it may be best to also mention that they are artifacts and are not generally available unless a DM places them into a campaign.  [This may be worth linking to](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79919/22566)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast the OP's question was "are there any mechanics", no more. The eye and hand of vecna definitely is an example of these mechanics, regardless of (not) being used in campaigns.

Comment: "discuss it's balance and quality" — was it really what OP asked? @NautArch

Comment: I think Naut's point on linking 3d party material is that its quality varies quite a bit.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Is that limited to 3rd-party material, in your experience?

Comment: @MarkWells I personally find that the UA "test" stuff is all over the map, but it is clearly marked as "a work in progress" whereas 3d party material tries to assert a certain level of polish.  But it's all over the map.  I just stopped wasting money on (And SCAG bears the marks of 3d party quality problems IMO ... but that's me)