# As a DM can I set a different skill check DC for each player?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage, difficulty-class

Let's say that the players find some text. Even though it is written in common, it actually is a translation of an ancient Elvish prayer. One of the players is an elf, the other human and the 3rd one an Aarakocra. It seems only fair that it should be easier to figure out what the text is for the elf that was raised in Elvish culture rather than the human. For the aarakocra that was raised on a different plane it could be even harder.

In DnD 5e, can I set a different DC for the skill check to figure out what the text is depending on which player attempts it, or should I rely on advantage and disadvantage only? One of the cons of using ADV/DIS in this case is that even if the elf fails at figuring it out, he knows he had an ADV for an unknown reason, which might give out a hint to the players.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: [Does familiarity (or lack thereof) with subject modify the skill DC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107406/62294)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think it is. Thanks for pointing me to the resource :)

Comment: This sounds like the perfect time to give certain players advantage or disadvantage.  Set the DC to 15 (moderate difficulty), give your Elven player advantage, give your Aarakocra player disadvantage, and leave your human with neither.  All are attempting the same difficulty, but the advantage/disadvantage makes it more or less difficult per character due to their own personal situations.