# Help, in 5th edition D&D do my modifiers go up, how and why?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-levels

In dnd 5th edition, do my modifiers go up when I level up and how and why?

Comment: @Miniman In 4e, *all* modifiers go up, so I think this question is more reasonable than it seems on the surface.

Comment: Don't answer incoherent questions please.  Elias, can you explain a little more about what exactly you're asking about, which "modifiers" you want to know about, etc.  Most of the character progression is explained in your class description in the rules, maybe double check and then edit your question to clarify what you find unclear.

Comment: @mxyzplk Obviously I found the question coherent, or I wouldn't have answered.

Comment: While I agree with starwed that this question is clear, it shows no research effort and is basically "Read this Chapter of the Player's Handbook to me please."

Answer (score 12):

## Mostly yes

Most of the numbers on your character sheet either have, or can have an upward trend to them. However when and how often these numbers advance depends on which modifier you're talking about.

### Proficiency Bonus

Your character's primary modifier is his Proficiency Bonus. This begins at +2 at level 1, and maxes out at +6 at level 17. It's progress is indicated by the "Proficiency Bonus" column in your class's table.

### Ability Modifiers

Your ability modifiers (e.g. Strength Bonus, Dexterity Bonus, and so on) increase when your ability scores increase. The main way that your ability scores increase is through the Ability Score Improvement feature listed in your class's table.

Whenever you receive an Ability Score Improvement, you have a choice between three options:

- Increase one score by two.
- Increase two scores by one.
- Gain a feat.

How often you receive an Ability Score Improvement is dependent on your class, but is typically once every four levels.

Note that this increases your ability *score*, rather than your ability *modifier*. So increasing a score from 15 to 16 will increase your modifier from +2 to +3. But increasing from 16 to 17 will still leave you with a +3 modifier.

### Other Numbers

Other numbers (such as armor class) can also be improved, but you usually do so by buying better gear.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, modifiers do typically scale with level.

This is chiefly accomplished through the idea of a proficiency bonus.  (PHB p. 12)  This starts at +2 at 1st level, and rises to a max of +6 at level 17.  (p. 15)   Obviously, this is a much more limited range than you'd see in previous editions of the game.  (This is a concept the designers have called [bounded accuracy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44826/are-peoples-competencies-really-as-flat-in-dd-5e-as-its-math-suggests).)

You add the proficiency bonus on the following, but only when you're proficient with them:

- Attack rolls with weapons
- Ability checks using skills and tools
- Saving throws

You also add it to attacks and save DCs related to spells you cast.