# Are there any ways to increase weapon attack bonuses, besides, perhaps advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

After running a few combat encounters with my PCs, I've noticed that they appear to be missing their attacks more than I've expected. I was wondering if there are ways for them to increase the attack bonuses with their weapons in order to hit more often. As a DM, what should I do or instruct them to do?

Comment: The answer to a straight "how do I get +x to hit" is simple, but to actually address the underlying issue, I think we need a few more details: what were they fighting? What level are your PCs? How often do you expect them to hit?

Comment: This is also heavily be impacted by what they are fighting. A Knight is a lot harder to hit (AC 18) than a Grell (AC 12) despite being both CR 3 opponents. This is all part of the AC/HP/Atk/Dmg balance that determines a creature's CR. Some creatures are intentionally very hard to hit...but may have fewer hit points or not do as much damage in exchange

Comment: In wonder how you feel about this post becoming the canonical "what are all the ways to get an attack bonus" Q&A that it looks like it's quickly becoming. If you're *not* a fan of that you should edit this question to make clearer your situation. In fact, (and maybe I'm being a little trigger-happy, feel free voters to overrule me) I'm going to go ahead and put the question on hold until we've heard your response to either Icyfire or me.

Comment: How do you calculate attacks? It is quite easy to hit in DnD5, if you see otherwise, you might be calculating something wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways. Below is a (currently) non-exhaustive list. For your information, fifth edition Dungeons and Dragons is based on the principle of [bounded accuracy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44826/are-peoples-competencies-really-as-flat-in-dd-5e-as-its-math-suggests), which means that the designers purposefully made flat bonuses rarer than in previous editions. That being said, on to the list :

- Achieving certain character levels (the proficiency bonus at level 1 is +2, but becomes +3 at level 5, +4 at level 9, +5 at level 13, and +6 at level 17. For example, a Rogue 2 / Fighter 4 [character level 6] would have a proficiency bonus of +3)
- Ability Score Improvement towards the ability used to attack (Each +2 put on an ability score increases the attack bonus by 1, for a maximum score of 20, giving +5. The first ASI is available at class level 4)
- The Bard's Bardic Inspiration (add a d6 to an attack roll. Later becomes a bigger die)
- The Cleric's Bless [level 1 spell] (add a d4 to an attack roll)
- [From Xanathar's Guide to Everything] The Forge Cleric's Blessing of the Forge feature (make a non-magical weapon magical to give it a +1 to attack rolls)
- The Paladin's Elemental Weapon [level 3 spell] (make a non-magical weapon magical to give it a +1 to attack rolls. If the spell is cast with a higher level slot, the bonus increases, for a maximum of +3)
- Gained magical weapons (grant a fixed attack roll bonus when used to attack. The maximum is +3)
- [From Xanathar's Guide to Everything] The Kensei monk's Sharpen the Blade feature at level 11 (spend up to 3 ki points to give that much of an attack roll bonus to a weapon that doesn't already have a magical weapon attack bonus)
- Gained magical ability-boosting items (increase an ability score which, incidentally, increases its bonus if said ability is used to attack. Example : Belt of Giant Strength increases Strength score)
- The Battle Master Fighter's Precision maneuver at level 3 (add a d8 to an attack roll. Later becomes a bigger die. Can also be obtained via the Martial Adept feat for a d6 attack roll bonus)
- The Archery fighting style (add +2 to ranged weapon attack rolls. Available to Fighters and Rangers)
- The War Cleric's Divine Strike Channel Divinity at level 2 (add +10 to an attack roll. Can be given to another player's attack roll at level 6. Also available to an Oath of Conquest Paladin [Xanathar's Guide to Everything] at level 3)
- The Oath of Devotion Paladin's Sacred Weapon Channel Divinity at level 3 (add Charisma bonus on top of the regular ability bonus for an attack roll)
- The Wild Magic Sorcerer's Bend Luck feature at level 6 (add a d4 to an attack roll)

So, for example, a level 1 character (proficiency bonus of +2) usually has at least a 16 (+3) in the ability he uses to attack. That's already a +5 to hit. If a friendly Bard gives the character a Bardic Inspiration, that's another +1d6 for a single attack. If a friendly Cleric uses Bless on the character, that's yet another +1d4 for all attacks for up to 1 minute. If the character attacks with a ranged weapon while having the Archery Fighting style, that's yet another +2.

Comment: If you find other ways, please comment them here, and I'll add them in the list.

Comment: The *Improved Pact Weapon* Invocation from XGtE will turn a pact weapon with no bonus to hit into a +1 magical weapon. Also, although you hardly needed to mention it, the spell *Magic Weapon* isn't mentioned in this list!

Comment: One more thing to add (thought it will rarely come up): a 20th level Ranger can add their wisdom modifier to an attack roll once per turn, if they are attacking one of their "favored enemies."

Comment: Hexblade’s curse albeit not often is a good way as well.